# I'm trying to do a Custom UITableViewCell but I can't show the results on the table

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uitableview

I have a json that brings the data from a server, so have 3 different classes and a view controller

this is the main class

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return poi.count
}
//the method returning each cell of the list
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell

    //getting the hero for the specified position
    let hero: poiLista
    hero = poi[indexPath.row]

    //displaying values
    cell.labelName.text = hero.nombre
    cell.labelID.text? = "\(hero.id_poi)"

    return cell
}
```

This is part of the function I use to list te data

```
    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        //exiting if there is some error
        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }
        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            var teamJSON: NSDictionary!
            teamJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            //getting the JSON array teams from the response
            let teams: NSArray = teamJSON["teams"] as! NSArray


            //looping through all the json objects in the array teams
            for i in 0 ..< teams.count{

                //getting the data at each index
                let poiID: Int = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary)["id_poi"] as! Int
                let poiName: String = (teams[i] as! NSDictionary)["nombre"] as! String

                self.poi.append(poiLista(
                    id_poi: poiID,
                    nombre: poiName
                ))

                //displaying the data
                print("id -> ", poiID)
                print("name -> ", poiName)
            }
             //displaying data in tableview
            self.tableViewMuseo.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()
```

from the json I get raw followed data so I want it to be shown in the table but it's not working

id ->  1
name -> School

Comment: It's missing from your example but have you assigned a UITableViewDataSource to your UITableView?

Comment: Did you assign TableView delegates. 1- Datasource and 2-Delegate